# Why are Mahayana texts in Sanskrit?

Tags: history, language

Based on the quote below, it seemed that the Buddha did not allow his teachings to be translated to the royal or priestly language of Sanskrit, that was the liturgical language of Brahmanism, the language of classical literature and the language used by the royal court.

The common people at the time did not speak Sanskrit in their daily conversations. They spoke various dialects of Prakrit. The Buddha wanted his teachings to be transmitted in the dialects of the common people.

It appears that Pali, although not a genuinely spoken language of the past, seems to be a mix of various Prakrit dialects from Buddha's time, that underwent partial Sanskritization.

It also makes sense to me that the Pali Canon was transmitted mostly by oral tradition and was written down only late in its history compared to Mahayana texts because Sanskrit was the main written language for a long time in northern India. This is similar to the role of Latin in European history.

I also guess that the Chinese scholar monks who visited India, took with them the Sanskrit Mahayana texts back to China, instead of the Pali Canon, partly because the Sanskrit texts were committed to writing much earlier, while the Pali Canon was still transmitted mostly orally at the time.

Question:
If the Buddha did not want his teachings to be taught in Sanskrit, why and how did the Indian Mahayana texts (agamas, sutras, vinaya etc.) end up being in Sanskrit?

According to the (Theravada) Vinaya from [Cullavagga, fifth Khandaka, chapter 33](http://www.sacred-texts.com/bud/sbe20/sbe20048.htm):

> And so sitting those Bhikkhus spake to the Blessed One thus:
>
> 'At the present time, Lord, Bhikkhus, differing in name, differing in
>   lineage, differing in birth, differing in family, have gone forth
>   (from the world). These corrupt the word of the Buddhas by (repeating
>   it in) their own dialect. Let us, Lord, put the word of the Buddhas
>   into (Sanskrit) verse.'
>
> 'How can you, O foolish ones, speak thus, saying, "Let us, Lord, put
>   the word of the Buddhas into verse?" This will not conduce, O foolish
>   ones, either to the conversion of the unconverted, or to the increase
>   of the converted; but rather to those who have not been converted
>   being not converted, and to the turning back of those who have been
>   converted.'
>
> And when the Blessed One had rebuked those Bhikkhus, and had delivered
>   a religious discourse, he addressed the Bhikkhus, and said:
>
> **'You are not, O Bhikkhus, to put the word of the Buddhas into
>   (Sanskrit) verse. Whosoever does so, shall be guilty of a dukkata. I
>   allow you, O Bhikkhus, to learn the word of the Buddhas each in his
>   own dialect.'**

Comment: This question built upon wrong assumption, if the OP is not with special agenda. I doubt the OP's asking in his sincerity, from various posts by the OP in this forum, he is a Theravadin. And, very important, **the scripts being translated to Chinese Sutras** were not Sanskrit, they were from different dialects, **major script was Prakrit**.

Comment: Some fragments of original scrolls are still kept in some monasteries esp. those dedicated to the great Dharma Masters such as Kumarajiva and Xuanzang, also scrolls discovered in Dunhuang Caves are in dialectic scripts, not Sanskrit.

Comment: [The 1st Buddhist Council had organized the 12 sections (major portions were Chinese Mahayana Sutras) of Sutras and written down on white-cloth in 4 scripts](https://celestory.com/history-and-facts-of-the-buddhist-scriptures-i-500-arhats-collecting-the-teachings/) (*excluded Pali script for it was not invented until 1000 years later by Buddhaghosa*), recorded in Agamas and Vinayas. I wonder if that piece of equivalent Pali Sutta remained untranslated yet or missing - ? I will write an answer when have time. But I'm afraid here too many *pretenders* who don't care or respect truth.

Comment: @Mishu米殊 You're welcomed to write an answer. From reading, I found that there were around 18 schools of Indian Buddhism originating from Mahasamghika and Sthaviravada (not Theravada), who have suttas or agamas in either Pali or Buddhist Hybrid Sanskrit (BHS). Pali is partially Sanskritized mix of Prakrit dialects, while BHS is post-Vedic Sanskrit with some Prakrit influence. Old, middle and new parts of the canon have linguistic variations - so not 2 (Pali, BHS) but more. So, it's not black or white. It's all many shades of gray. It's unfortunate that most of these schools are extinct today.

Comment: Thanks @ruben2020. Early 18 Schools' Sutras and Vinayas are inherited in the Chinese Tripitaka, even Mahasamgika's the most original. Faxian travelled to Ceylon but only took back Mahisasaka's, your qouted Pali vinaya when it produced? Why no Chinese pilgrims took back any existing "Pali Canon", because oral? - But Mahasamgika's wasn't written (not oral, but because vinaya for Bhiksus only didn't want laity learnt to criticize), Chinese Bhiksu learnt it by heart and installed to Chinese Samgha. **Pali 1st made its presence in Pali Canon, its artificially created to write Pali Suttas, a fact**.

Comment: @Mishu米殊 Do take a look at the Introduction chapter of [this book](http://www.ahandfulofleaves.org/documents/A%20History%20of%20Pali%20Literature_Law.pdf). The name "Pali" and the script to write it is maybe new and/or artificial, but the language bearing the name is simply an extinct Prakrit dialect (probably from Magadha or Kosala), replaced by Classical Sanskrit and modern dialects. It's extinct for all purposes except the Pali Canon. Some even speculate that "Pali" is shortened form of "Pataliputra" or "Pataligrama", the name of the Magadhan town or village where it may have originated.

Comment: @Mishu米殊 It could be the case that Chinese pilgrim monks did not take the Pali Canon back to China, for the same reason why Theravadins did not take the Heart Sutra or the Lotus Sutra. The different sects simply did not recognize or accept each other.

Comment: Your book resulted a 13MB of data I thought it was a link @ruben2020, the book is endorsed by a Sri Lankan PhD who promoted Theravada totalled 600-700 pages I wonder if its neutral opinion, if worth to read. From Chinese Wikipedia, Sri Lankan monks claimed discoverying a Pali version of *Vimuttimagga* in a monastery but later carbon-dated to modern "artifact" of recent made, I lost faith of the sincerity and trust of the Sri Lankan scholars. That said, Sri Lanka is great with natural resources like tea, ruby; the people are diligent and royal. (Vim. is regarded...

Comment: ... the mother Sastra of *Visudhimagga*, existed only in Chinese Tripitaka.)There are different versions of same Sutras from different sources, e.g. Heart Sutras 6 versions, Lankavatara 2, individual Sutras from Agamas, Samyukta Agama likely from Ceylon, but WHY PALI CANON NEVER COLLECTED BY CHINESE PILGRIMS??? They were to collect all the treasures left by the Buddha, undiscrimingly, from all different schools. I wrote an answer but my computer hanged, not sure if I could recover. During writing I found many sources giving accounts on Pali are edited - edited to argue its a real language...

Comment: ... I'm not sure if its worth to answer this post, obviously an individual cannot resist the *institution*. The more I listed as evidences the skillful they can edit the facts. If you, and all those enjoy colaborating consciously or unconsciously in editing a Buddist Bible, like the church did on Christainity, it is your own Karma.

Comment: Anyhow Buddhism is at its deteriorating after 2500 years. You can advertise all the early Buddhists were following unauthentic Mahayana teaching from ~425BC to late 200 years ago (Mahayana was domainate doctrines during *sad-dharma* period the 1st 500 years for Buddha Shakyamuni, mentioned also in Pali Canon), only now you learnt people, Theravadins and Western scholars are learning the authentic Suttas based on Pali Canon the Early Buddhist Texts - Buddhist Bible. Sure there are many believers nodding heads clapping feet to approve. But these people can talk to our toes only.

Comment: @Mishu米殊 I just downloaded and started reading the book "[Sects and Sectarianism: the origins of Buddhist schools](http://santifm.org/santipada/2010/sects-sectarianism/)" by Bhikkhu Sujato. I think it will be interesting.

Comment: Believe in the Island History of [Ceylon] the Dīpavaṁsa, Theravadin Sujato Bhikkhu who wrote Lotus Sutra a fake @ruben2020. All other Early 17/18 Schools schismatic except one on Ceylon called Theravada (Wikipedia said many scholars contesting Dipavamsa's trustfulness, haven't rechecked since, if it's edited?) Can Sujato Bhikkhu read Chinese 異部宗輪論, 部執異論, or Xuanzang, Yijing, etc their travel journals. Alas! Only Theravada were not schismatic + Dipavamsa correct + Buddha speaking Pali + Sujato right, all others were wrong learning unauthentic Mahayana teachings faked by the 17/18 Schools :)

Comment: @Mishu米殊 Actually, Sujato Bhikkhu isn't really against Mahayana. He wrote in the Sects and Sectarianism book that he doesn't agree with the Dipavamsa: "*They (Mahayana) are ‘schismatic’ and it is impossible to accept them as part of the same communion. This view, ultimately traced to the Dīpavaṁsa, underlies the position taken by many mainstream Theravādins today. I intend to show how the Dīpavaṁsa’s position is incoherent and implausible, and that a more reasonable depiction of the origins of Buddhist schools can be constructed from a sympathetic reading of all the sources.*"

Comment: Let's make it the last, you may write, I'll read @ruben2020. Sujato in the conclusive pages argued the regional Early Schools mythologized the Buddha to gain authenticity - mythologized is an old tactic to defame Mahayana (computer hanged again I can't check) - devil is in the detail. Perhaps only you can believe Sujato not against Mahayana, read his articles. Any Bhikkhu openly written Lotus Sutra fake can never retrieve what spilt; even against conduct of a Bhikkhu. Perhaps just the same reason Chinese Pilgrims never taken Pali Canon, but also never made comment on it, just ignored it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid any answer to this is going to be speculative, so not a perfect SE question. Here is my theory:

Most of the early Mahayana texts were written either in [Hybrid Sanskrit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddhist_Hybrid_Sanskrit) or in [Gandhari Prakrit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C4%81ndh%C4%81r%C4%AB_language) because their authors were the descendants of Aryans living in the [Gandhara](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gandhara) region. Historically, that area has always been much more "sanskritized" than the rest of India, see below for my explanation as to why.  So when Buddhism reached Gandhara, it was only natural for the educated locals to write their thoughts about Buddhism in a language that they both spoke *and* knew how to write - and that was Hybrid Gandhari Sanskrit.

Here is some background information in support of this thesis:

1. As you all know, Classical Sanskrit is an idealized written form of the language that the original Aryans actually spoke (some modern scientists call it "Prakrit" and other call it "Vedic Sanskrit"). Sort of like Classical Latin is an idealized written form of the language that the original Romans actually spoke.
2. Originally, Aryans came from Iran and settled in what today is south of Afghanistan, along what used to be [Sarasvati river](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sarasvati_River). Then, when the tectonic shifts in Himalayas made Sarasvati change its course and start falling into Ganges, the Aryan tribes started migrating further east, carrying their language and culture with them, and mixing with the indigenous population. This led to a range of dialects emerging along the Ganges, from the purest form of Vedic Sanskrit in the west to the most corrupted vernaculars in the east. This process was accompanied by social stratification, with "more civilized" Aryans on the top and "less civilized" locals at the bottom - this was how the infamous casts or [varna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varna_(Hinduism))s begun.

   Sorry about the map labels being in Russian, I drew it a long time ago and don't have time at the moment to fix the labels. But from the overall shape and the colors, I hope you can see the state of Aryan assimilation by the time the Buddha comes on stage. The blue states on the left are more Aryan, speaking almost pure Sanskrit - and the orange states on the right are more the original people, speaking their own languages partially mixed with Sanskrit to form various dialects like e.g. Pali. The region of Gandhara is not highlighted on my map, but it is that area with multiple rivers  to the left of the leftmost Indian state.

   [image: Map of Ancient India]
3. There was a big university there in [Gandhara](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gandhara), called [Takshasila University](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/University_of_Ancient_Taxila) - and thanks to the proximity of Persian and Greek Empires I suppose this region was a lot more educated and literate than the rest of India, back in the day.
4. Most of the Mahayana scripts written in Sanskrit (either Hybrid or Gandhari) were discovered at archaeological sites located in the Gandhara area.
5. Many of the great Mahayana lineages recognized in Tibetan Buddhism, trace their beginning to enlightened masters from [Oddiyana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oddiyana) which is basically the same area.
6. [Sarvastivada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sarvastivada) school left their version of Canon written down in Sanskrit, and we know that Sarvastivada was essentially centered in that same very region of Gandhara/Oddiyana.
7. Milinda-Panha (Questions of King Milinda) - a late Canonical text whose story is set in Sagala, a city just to the east of Gandhara region, was probably originally written in the Gandhari language.
8. At least *some* of the Mahayana sutras only available in Chinese show linguistical evidence of having been translated from the Gandhari dialect of Sanskrit.

All this is to say that ancient people of Gandhara/Oddiyana who wrote Buddhist texts in Sanskrit did *not* violate Buddha's rule prescribing people to "learn the word of the Buddhas each in his own dialect" - because Sanskrit was a written version of the language they actually spoke.

Then, from Gandhara, Buddhism has spread to other countries including China via the Silk Road, as well as Tibet.

Comment: Thanks, Andrei. [Here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/28/Mahajanapadas_%28c._500_BCE%29.png) is an equivalent map in English.

Comment: Yes, perfect. One thing it does not show though is the degree of Aryan assimilation as it changes from west to east, as I show with blue and orange colors.

Answer (score 2):

Further to Andrei's answer, I imagine that Sanskrit or equivalent might have been like English is in India today -- i.e. many people know it (as a living language) and use it normally whenever they communicate with someone from/in a different State -- less of a "dead" and priests-and-academics-only language than Latin is now, maybe the bourgeoisie (such as that was) and any travellers (maybe wanderers) would have known it too, and so it's not surprising to find Sanskrit's being used everywhere other than in the native State[s].

But it's nice of the Buddha to approve of the teaching's being in the vernacular, and preserving it that way.

As evidence [there is this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_lingua_francas#Sanskrit) ...

> Sanskrit historically served as a *lingua franca* throughout the majority of India.

For some further background [there is also this](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/37575/2703) which claims that -- in the 7th century AD -- it was the urban merchants who tended to support Buddhism -- and that these merchants were influenced by the ruling class, and influenced by which remote States they were trading with -- unlike the peasants (farmers), who were more isolated in the country-side and more "Hindu" than "Buddhist".